# CodeLite MinGW how to change temporary batch file path

Tags: mingw, mingw32, codelite

I'm using CodeLite and mingw64 compiler on win10.
When I build my C++ projects, it creates a temporary batch file in the %temp% folder with a structure r"make\d+-\d+.bat" (example: make9036-20.bat). Now Avast thinks those are viruses, so it blocks them. I don't want to exclude the whole %temp% folder, so imo., making a subfolder for temp "make... .bat" files and excluding it would be the best solution.

I found the "Intermediate Directory" setting in the Project Settings, but that won't affect the .bat files.

...So, I would like to know, how to change the default CodeLite/MinGW temp files path to something else (like %temp%\mingw.tmp or similar).

Thank you for any kind of help, TTS

Comment: Can Avast do globs in exceptions? E.g. can you exclude `temp/make*.bat`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good idea, I'll try to find out if that's possible. I've discovered something called "command line exception" and that might lead somewhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I finally took time to ask about regex on avast forums and to solve this inconvenience. It turns out avast supports wildcards so * and ? do work... I was just dumb not to try your suggested string right away. `temp\make*-*.bat` exception solved my problem.